Jooq casts my UUID even though its already of type uuid, why?
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events
(
      id            UUID NOT NULL,
      type_id       UUID,
      occurred_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

jood code:
val queryDsl = dslContext.select(EventFields).from(EVENTS)
                .where(
                    (EVENTS.TYPE_ID.isNull)
                        .or(EVENTS.TYPE_ID.eq(query.typeId.id))
                )

model id code:
import java.util.UUID

data class TypeId(val id: UUID) {
    constructor (id: String) : this(UUID.fromString(id))

    override fun toString(): String = id.toString()
}

Query:
where ("public"."events"."type_id" = cast('d0c6a2a7-2032-4dd7-b2b1-77a554262af7' as uuid))

Why cast?
I tried to get rid of this casting as it affects my index performance
My index:
CREATE INDEX company_employee_occurred_at_idx 
ON balance_state_event (id, type_id, occurred_at DESC);

In my explain query plain one of the line is:
Filter: ((type_id IS NULL) OR (type_id = '390caffd-9c3b-4ea4-b5e2-6ae342268141'::uuid))

why an explicit filter if the index is there?

I think that it is unavoidable, as the actual value has to be serialized between jvm representation and query/database representation. Also, I would find it weird that this cast to affect performance. Can you provide more detail about the performance issue ? Have you seen better performance with a manually crafted query ?

I added a little more context, I wanted to know if this is unavoidable, since both jvm and postgres had the same type UUID, but I have an index and still an explicit filtering is happening in the query plan, wanted to know why

Index Cond: (id), but then Filter: ((type_id IS NULL) OR (type_id = '390caffd-9c3b-4ea4-b5e2-6ae342268141'::uuid)) happens seperately


Why cast?

There has been a relatively recent fix in jOOQ where all UUID bind values are now cast to their type explicitly for SQLDialect.POSTGRES:

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/16334

The fix has been applied to versions:

3.20.0
3.19.6
3.18.13
3.17.22

It is necessary in a lot of edge cases and not-so-edge cases. jOOQ doesn't hard-code all of these cases to make a more specific decision based on the context, it just casts all UUID typed bind values, just like it auto-casts all of these typed bind values:

Enum typed
Interval typed
JSON typed
XML typed
Spatial typed

And possibly more, in the future.
This answers the question you asked (the one from the title).

I tried to get rid of this casting as it affects my index performance

I don't think this cast affects your performance. The bind value is a constant, and casting it doesn't change anything. Without the cast, there would still be an implicit cast as types get promoted.
However, your OR predicate is a more likely problem:
((type_id IS NULL) OR (type_id = '390caffd-9c3b-4ea4-b5e2-6ae342268141'::uuid))

Do check why in your case, no BitmapOr operation appears in your execution plan. It is hard to say from the little information you provided. In a more minimal example, this works just fine:
create table t (i uuid);
create index i on t (i);
insert into t select uuid_generate_v4() from generate_series(1, 1000000) as t (i);

explain
select *
from t
where i is null or i = cast('390caffd-9c3b-4ea4-b5e2-6ae342268141' as uuid)

Producing:
|QUERY PLAN                                                                         |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=8.87..12.88 rows=1 width=16)                          |
|  Recheck Cond: ((i IS NULL) OR (i = '390caffd-9c3b-4ea4-b5e2-6ae342268141'::uuid))|
|  ->  BitmapOr  (cost=8.87..8.87 rows=1 width=0)                                   |
|        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on i  (cost=0.00..4.43 rows=1 width=0)               |
|              Index Cond: (i IS NULL)                                              |
|        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on i  (cost=0.00..4.43 rows=1 width=0)               |
|              Index Cond: (i = '390caffd-9c3b-4ea4-b5e2-6ae342268141'::uuid)       |

This shows that you probably have another question to ask, best in a new question, as this one is about jOOQ and casting, not about your actual performance issue.

Thanks, that makes a lot of sense, I will look at the OR condition part and try to get rid of it.
